# IBOutlets and Custom views

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I have a UIViewController that requires 5 subviews which contain a UIImageView and a text UILabel.

I would like to have these as IBOutlet so have the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) MyCustomView *customerView1
@property (nonatomic, weak) MyCustomView *customerView2
etc
```

I then have the following class which create these custom views in code:

```
#import "MyCustomView.h"

@implementation MyCustomView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        //[self setupView:frame andKeyColor:color];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andKeyColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setupView:frame andKeyColor:color];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setupView:(CGRect)frame andKeyColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    UIImageView *colorKeySquare = [self createColorKeySquare:frame andKeyColor:color];
    [self addSubview:colorKeySquare];

    UILabel *titleTextLabel = [self createTitleLabel:colorKeySquare.frame];
    self.titleText = titleTextLabel;
    [self addSubview:self.titleText];
}

- (UIImageView *)createColorKeySquare:(CGRect)frame andKeyColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y);
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(20, 20);
    UIImageView *colorKeySquare = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, size.width, size.height)];

    [colorKeySquare setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    return colorKeySquare;
}

- (UILabel *)createTitleLabel:(CGRect)frame
{
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(frame), frame.origin.y);
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width - frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
    UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, size.width, size.height)];

    return textLabel;
}

@end
```

I have hooked everything up correctly. However when I go to access the UILabel on one of my properties it always returns nil. The UILabel is not being allocated at any point.

If do the following: self.myCustomView1.titleLabel.text = @"Hello"; I get this when I print the object in the debugger:

```
Printing description of self->_nationalKey->_titleText:
```

What's the best way to go about setting up a custom view in code and having it associated with an IBOutlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know when you call `initWithFrame:andKeyColor:` but there are two main initialisers in UIView `initWithFrame:` which is called when you create view programmatically and `initWithCoder:` which is called when you create view in xib/storyboard.

In your example you should override `initWithCoder:`

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder 
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setupControls];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Greg. That method gets called perfectly. I can't upvote you as I don't have enough reputation at this moment in time. Those init methods were added in case I need to create in code which is the way I have always done custom views.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to init a view:

1. load from storyboard/xib

   In this case when you want access the view in code you need a `IBOutlet`
2. init by code

   In this case you don't need a `IBOutlet` at all

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, strong) MyCustomView *customerView1
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Greg has provided the method I needed. I have used storyboard/xib's before however never for custom views. Normally I don't have a property and just create and add in code. I wanted to have an IBOutlet and then set the custom view in code.